# Why is React.FunctionComponent preferred over conventional function definitions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've always defined React components (with typescript) as:

```
function MyComponent(props: PropsType): React.ReactElement | null {
    //...
}
```

Online I see a lot of examples like:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = (props: PropsType) => {
    //...
}
```

I understand they are pretty much the same, but what is the preferred convention in the Typescript community?

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [React-Typescript Cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet) on Github

> You can also write components with `React.FunctionComponent` (or the
>   shorthand `React.FC`):

```
const App: React.FC<{ message: string }> = ({ message }) => (  
  <div>{message}</div>
);
```

> Some differences from the "normal function" version:
>
> - It provides typechecking and autocomplete for static properties like `displayName`, `propTypes`, and `defaultProps` - **However**, there
>     are currently known issues using `defaultProps` with
>     `React.FunctionComponent`. See [this issue for
>     details](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet/issues/87)
> - It provides an implicit definition of `children` (see below) - however there are some issues with the implicit `children` type (e.g.
>     [DefinitelyTyped#33006](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33006)),
>     and it might considered better style to be explicit about components
>     that consume `children`, anyway.

```
const Title: React.FunctionComponent<{ title: string }> = ({  
children, title }) => <div title={title}>{children}</div>;
```

> - *In the future*, it may automatically mark props as `readonly`, though that's a moot point if the props object is destructured in the
>     constructor.
> - `React.FunctionComponent` is explicit about the return type, while the normal function version is implicit (or else needs additional
>     annotation).
>
> In most cases it makes very little difference which syntax is used,
>   but the `React.FC` syntax is slightly more verbose without providing
>   clear advantage, so precedence was given to the "normal function"
>   syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Boy With Silver Wings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57479180/2050629) - The core advantage is that the arrow function expression component (`const Foo () => <div>Hello</div>`) itself could be typed:

```
const Foo: YourOwnTypeAliasOrInterface = () => <div>Hello</div>
```

`React.FC` implements as being said a couple of types for you (children, or possible return types). You can't do that with your named function component:

```
function Foo<YourOwnTypeAliasOrInterface>() { // this does not work!! (Only with generics)
  return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

TL;TR with `React.FunctionalComponent` you simply have to type less, because types such as return type and children is already defined.

```
type FooProps = {
  title: string;
} & React.FC // <-- intersection type, so it has FooProps and React.FC typings

const Foo: FooProps = ({ children, title }) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create React App recently [dropped](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) `FC`/`FunctionComponent` type usage from the TypeScript template.

---

#### Downsides of `FC`:

- implicit optional `children` - better define your props API explicitely
- no generic component creation possible
- no need to have explicit `ReactElement | null` return type, which in addition is [not accurate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render); it can be 1) better inferred automatically by TS or 2) set explicitely
- `FC` is just a wrapper for statics like `contextTypes`, `propTypes`, etc. which aren't needed in most cases
- doesn't work well with `defaultProps` (Note: JS default args should be [preferred](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/createlement-rfc/text/0000-create-element-changes.md#deprecate-defaultprops-on-function-components) anyway)
- no need to remember "magic" types - just use functions for components
- doesn't make your code (much) leaner

---

So in summary, I would rather state the opposite: plain (arrow) functions > `React.FC`.